# Calculating a value in SQL using previous row's values and current row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to recreate the following in SQL where value at date of transaction needs to be calculated and value from other columns can be queried directly. It needs to add current value and transaction for first row of each type to get the value for 'value at date of transaction' and then for subsequent rows of that type, it needs to add 'value at date of transaction' from previous row to the 'transaction' value to get 'value at date of transaction' for current row. This process needs to start over for each type. Is this possible to recreate in SQL Server?

| Type | Current Value | Transaction | Date of transaction | Value at date of transaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 2 | 12/31/2001 | 7 |
| A | 5 | -3 | 12/30/2001 | 4 |
| A | 5 | -1 | 12/29/2001 | 3 |
| A | 5 | 6 | 12/28/2001 | 9 |
| B | 100 | 20 | 12/31/2001 | 120 |
| B | 100 | -50 | 12/30/2001 | 70 |
| B | 100 | -10 | 12/29/2001 | 60 |
| B | 100 | 30 | 12/28/2001 | 90 |
| C | 20 | 7 | 12/31/2001 | 27 |
| C | 20 | -3 | 12/30/2001 | 24 |

Comment: Thats a very strange way to store your data, 3 transaction records with the same starting value, except you ignore it in all but the first row?

Comment: If you add the DDL+DML to create that data as a temp table (or a DBFiddle) you make it much easier for someone to assist.

Comment: Also I highly suggest using an unambiguous date format. And do you really want to be calculating your total backwards in time? i.e. starting at the latest date and working backwards?

Comment: The starting value is just the current value in the system and is replicated on each row. The 'value at transaction date ' is what the vale would have been at that date. I am essentially trying to backtrack and see what the values for a particular type were historically.

I found this: https://learnsql.com/blog/what-is-a-running-total-and-how-to-compute-it-in-sql/

It essentially shows how to do a cumulative sum based on values in one column for different types but does not address how to do it for values in 2 columns and first row of each type following a different logic.

Comment: Yes, I want to calculate total backwards as explained in my previous comment. Date format id mm/dd/yyyy. I am not sure what DDL or DML is. I will look it up and post it here. Appreciate your help with having me post the questions better!

Comment: the answer below shows DDL+DML to create the sample data in a table variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure seems odd to me.

But you can use the window function `sum() over()`

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Type] varchar(50),[Current Value] int,[Transaction] int,[Date of transaction] date)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('A',5,2,'12/31/2001')
,('A',5,-3,'12/30/2001')
,('A',5,-1,'12/29/2001')
,('A',5,6,'12/28/2001')
,('B',100,20,'12/31/2001')
,('B',100,-50,'12/30/2001')
,('B',100,-10,'12/29/2001')
,('B',100,30,'12/28/2001')
,('C',20,7,'12/31/2001')
,('C',20,-3,'12/30/2001')
 
Select * 
      ,[Value at date] = [Current Value]
                       + sum([Transaction]) over (partition by [Type] order by [Date of transaction] desc)
 from @YourTable
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte1
as (SELECT *,
/* conditional ROW_NUMBER to get the maxDate by Type and get only the Transaction Value+ immediately succeding row's Current Value*/
           CASE
               WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Date_of_transaction DESC) = 1 then
                   LAG(Current_Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Date_of_transaction) + [Transaction]
               else
                   [Transaction]
           end as Base
    FROM [Global_capturis_owner].[Book2]
   )
select Type,
       Current_Value,
       [Transaction],
       Date_of_transaction,
       /* Windowed function to compute the Running Total*/
       SUM(Base) OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Date_of_transaction DESC) as RunningTotal
from cte1
```